# Django: Require Checkbox to be ticked to Submit Form

Tags: python, django, forms, checkbox, widget

I'm creating a form in Django (using ModelForm). 
There are many checkboxes, and I want to make it so that one of these must be selected in order to submit the form. I don't mean any one checkbox, but one *specific* box. I can't find anything in the Django documentation. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: show your forms. also did `required=True` not work ?

Comment: @karthikr Where should the `required` option go?

Comment: in the form field definition. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#required

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Something like

```
from django import forms
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    check = forms.BooleanField(required = True)
    # your other form fields
```

For a BooleanField, `required = True` will check if the box is checked. This is because data will only be submitted if it is checked.

Source: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.BooleanField

> Validates that the value is True (e.g. the check box is checked) if the field has required=True.

Comment: how would this be done in the model instead, as my forms.py is just a list of fields to be included from the model, but my model specifies whether a field is allowed to be blank etc.

Comment: It seems useless to put a boolean required to be true in a model, but I guess you'd have to override the field's save method to check if it is set to True and raise ValidationError otherwise.