# django boolean in form always returns true

Tags: django

learning django, and trying to make a todo list.
A task is created first with only a task.name.  Then I go to a taskdetail.html, with a form for task.detail, task.duedate, and task.done.  The latter is a boolean that is true if the task is completed.
I have the following in my template:

`<input type="hidden" name="done" value=0 />
<input type="checkbox" name="done" value=1 {% if task.done %} checked {% endif %}>`

In my views.py, I have:

```
def taskdetail(request, task_id):
task = Task.objects.get(pk=task_id)
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = DetailTaskForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():            
        task.name = form.cleaned_data["name"]
        task.description = form.cleaned_data["description"]
        task.done = form.cleaned_data["done"]
        task.duedate = form.cleaned_data["duedate"]
        task.save()
        ...
```

Strange enough, task.done alsways ends up true. It's default is false, and I have verified that it is indeed false before task.done = form.cleaned_data["done"]

I read that somewhere that value=0 is the same as false, but that doesn't seem to work for me.  I also tried

```
<input type="hidden" name="done" value="" />
```

but then my form.is_valid returns false.

What could be the problem here? (I am working with Django 2.1 and python 3.7)

EDIT1:
Willem's answer put me on track, but my problem isn't completely solved yet.  I have now set task.done default to False, and made it not a required field.  I changed my template to:

```
<input type="hidden" name="done" value="" />
<input type="checkbox" name="done" value=1 {% if task.done %} checked {% endif %}>  
{% if task.done %}
     <input type="hidden" name="done" value="on" />
{% endif %}
```

the {{task.done}} that I send to the form is False, and I don't see how it can be manipulated and set to True in the form.  (only after POSTing)  So instead of checking if task.done == True, I should be able to check if the checkbox has been ticked.

Comment: The idea of a checkbox is that it is checked if it has a value, and false if it is *missing* in the post request..

Answer (score 1):

A checkbox is considered "checked" if it is part of the POST data, and unchecked if it is *not* in the POST data, as is specified in the [*Forms* section of the *W3 recommendations*](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#checkbox):

> **checkboxes**
>
> Checkboxes (and radio buttons) are on/off switches that may be toggled
>   by the user. A switch is `"on"` when the control element's checked
>   attribute is set. When a form is submitted, only "on" checkbox
>   controls can become successful.

You thus can use the above "trick" by *not* rendering the field in case the task is not done, like:

```
{% if task.done %}
<input type="hidden" name="done" value="on" />
{% endif %}
```

Comment: @PeterM.: well a `required=True` check, then this means the checkbox *must* be checked, so this is probably indeed something you do *not* want: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16988127/django-require-checkbox-to-be-ticked-to-submit-form

Comment: Indeed. See my EDIT.  The user should have the choice to check it or not, and the result of that check should then alter Task.done to True or leave it to it's default False

Comment: @PeterM.: ah in that case you can make two `<input>` fields, one checkbox (`done`), and a `hidden` (`old_done`). But why don't you fetch the "old done" from the database?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved with following code:

in forms.py, added required=False for done

```
class DetailTaskForm(TaskForm):
description = forms.CharField(max_length = 600)
done = forms.BooleanField(initial=False, required=False)
duedate = forms.DateField()
```

In my template: the value of "done" was set to "" by default, so that nothing was posted.  Only when the checkbox was checked, done gets a value (in this case "on" but any value will do.  Thanks Willem for putting me on track

```
<input type="hidden" name="done" value="" />
<input type="checkbox" name="done" value="on" {% if task.done %} checked {% endif %}>  
{% if task.done %}
   <input type="hidden" name="done" value="on" />
{% endif %}
```